# Backing Up mysql db from the command line

Tags: command-line, mysql

I am trying to backup my database and keep getting error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$ mysqldump -u root -p chandlers > backup_db.sql' at line 1

I am using the following command to launch the backup :

```
$ mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p chandlers > backup_db.sql
```

edit>>>>
This is how I connect to the db, this is a shortcut I have setup to open a command line :

```
C:\server2go\server2go\server\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost -P 7188 -u root
```

This works fine and connects, I have tried creating another like this >>

```
 C:\server2go\server2go\server\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe $ mysqldump -h localhost -P 7188 -u root -pchandlers > backup_db.sql
```

but I am getting an access denied error now.

Comment: you are running this from the command line, not from the MySQL console, right? The error suggests you are within the console.

Comment: ah I see I thought this was ran from the mysql console, I will try from the command line....

Comment: if i run it from the command line i get the following error :

Comment: C:\Users\Iain>$ mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p chandlers > backup_db.sql
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You type it without the `$` sign (This is just to show that it's a console command)

Comment: @IainSimpson: clarifications and other additions to a question should be edited into the question, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you're dealing with another issue, it deserves a new question.

Answer (score 6):

you can use mysqldump to backup mysql database.

Below is the script example to backup mysql database in command line:-

```
$ mysqldump -h localhost -u username -p database_name > backup_db.sql
```

If your mysql database is very big, you might want to compress your sql file.
Just use the mysql backup command below and pipe the output to gzip,
then you will get the output as gzip file.

```
$ mysqldump -u username -h localhost -p database_name | gzip -9 > backup_db.sql.gz
```

If you want to extract the .gz file, use the command below:-

```
$ gunzip backup_db.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be calling `mysqldump` from within mySQL, which is incorrect - it's a separate executable.

Call it from the command line instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `$ mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pchandlers > backup_db.sql`. Otherwise it seems fine to me.